# Getting " ValueError: Output of generator should be a tuple `(x, y, sample_weight)` or `(x, y)` " while

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am trying to train a cnn on the images stored in a folder named "Health".

```
train_data_dir = "Health"
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./256,
                                   rotation_range = 360,
                                   width_shift_range=0.1,
                                   height_shift_range=0.1,
                                   zoom_range=10,
                                   horizontal_flip=True,
                                   vertical_flip=True,
                                   data_format ="channels_last",validation_split=0.2) 

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(train_data_dir,
                                                    target_size =(img_width, img_height),
                                                    batch_size = batch_size,
                                                    class_mode = None,
                                                    subset='training') 

validation_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(train_data_dir,
                                                        target_size =(img_width, img_height),
                                                        batch_size = batch_size,
                                                        class_mode =None,
                                                        subset='validation')
history = model.fit_generator(generator=train_generator,
                             steps_per_epoch=train_generator.samples//batch_size,
                             epochs=10,
                             validation_data=validation_generator,
                             validation_steps=validation_generator.samples//batch_size)
```

I am getting the following error:

```
ValueError: Output of generator should be a tuple `(x, y, sample_weight)` or `(x, y)`. Found: [[[[0.         0.         0.        ]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your directory `Health` organized as stated in the documentation?

***directory***: string, path to the target directory. It should contain one subdirectory per class. Any PNG, JPG, BMP, PPM or TIF images inside each of the subdirectories directory tree will be included in the generator.

Why do you pass `class_mode = None`? `None` is intended for inference mode, i.e. prediction, no labels are returned by the generator. But you like to train the model, right?

Link to documentation and an example:

https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/

https://gist.github.com/fchollet/0830affa1f7f19fd47b06d4cf89ed44d

Comment: The health directory contains 2 sub directories - healthy and not_healthy... I believe 
"validation_split=0.2" should create train and validation automatically... I changed class_mode = binary and the training started! Thank You very much.

Comment: You're welcome :) Glad I could help, please feel free to accept this answer as best answer and help me push my karma, thanks.